# Tikz picture shifting the position of an arrow label

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-arrows

I've got the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
    \node (0) {\Large$0$};
    \node (1) [right of=0] {\Large$1$};
    \node (2) [right of=1] {\Large$2$};
    \node (3) [right of=2] {\Large$3$};
    \node (4) [right of=3] {\Large$\cdots$};
    \draw[->] (1.160) to node {\small$(0,1)$} (0.20);
    \draw[->] (1.200) to node [swap] {\small$(1,0)$} (0.340);
    \draw[->] (2.160) to node {\small$(0,1)$} (1.20);
    \draw[->] (2.200) to node [swap] {\small$(1,0)$} (1.340);
    \draw[->] (3.160) to node {\small$(0,1)$} (2.20);
    \draw[->] (3.200) to node [swap] {\small$(1,0)$} (2.340);
    \draw[->] (4.169) to node {\small$(0,1)$} (3.20);
    \draw[->] (4.191) to node [swap] {\small$(1,0)$} (3.340);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives me the following picture:

[image: messed up diagram]

It was basically working fine, but I decided to switch the directions of all the arrows, it previously gave me this:

[image: neat but backwards diagram]

which is basically what I want.

So my question is how do I adjust the label positions of my edges?

Comment: Maybe something like that example: ```\draw (0,0) -- (6,0) node[midway,fill=white] {Test};```? I don't  fully understand the question …

Comment: Since you specify all angles explicitly, you have to swap the positions of the `[swap]`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be happy to retract this answer, just in case nobody answers. The issue is that you specify all the angles explicitly. Therefore, what worked fine in one direction, won't work fine if you reverse the direction. So you could either exchange the angles, i.e. `160 <-> 200` and `20 <-> 340`, or, what is easier, swap the positions of the `[swap]`s. Of course, the results of these procedures differ.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
    \node (0) {\Large$0$};
    \node (1) [right of=0] {\Large$1$};
    \node (2) [right of=1] {\Large$2$};
    \node (3) [right of=2] {\Large$3$};
    \node (4) [right of=3] {\Large$\cdots$};
    \draw[->] (1.160) to node [swap] {\small$(0,1)$} (0.20);
    \draw[->] (1.200) to node {\small$(1,0)$} (0.340);
    \draw[->] (2.160) to node [swap] {\small$(0,1)$} (1.20);
    \draw[->] (2.200) to node {\small$(1,0)$} (1.340);
    \draw[->] (3.160) to node [swap] {\small$(0,1)$} (2.20);
    \draw[->] (3.200) to node {\small$(1,0)$} (2.340);
    \draw[->] (4.169) to node [swap] {\small$(0,1)$} (3.20);
    \draw[->] (4.191) to node {\small$(1,0)$} (3.340);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: moving the [swap] was a great and easy fix. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

an alternative solution: based on use of the `tikz` libraries `chains` and `positioning` and since seems to be all arrow labels the same, is used loop for drawing them between nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm,
  start chain = A going right,
  num/.style = {font=\Large, on chain=A},
                        ]
\node[num]  {$0$};      % node name: A-1
\node[num]  {$1$};
\node[num]  {$2$};
\node[num]  {$3$};
\node[num]  {$\cdots$}; % node name: A-5
%
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i-1)] in {5,...,2}
{
\draw[->,transform canvas={yshift=+1mm}]   (A-\i) -- node[above,font=\small] {$(0,1)$} (A-\j);
\draw[->,transform canvas={yshift=-1mm}]   (A-\i) -- node[below,font=\small] {$(1,0)$} (A-\j);
}
```

[image]